# How to balance last page of a LaTeX document?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am trying to balance the last page of my LaTeX document, i.e. a conference paper. I am using the `flushend` package to do it. All of it goes well except for the last line. The columns are balanced but the last line sticks out to the left. I have tried everything to sort it out but the last line stays the left aligned.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please register to this site in order to be able to comment later. We can't help you here without some code. Please show us a minimal compilable document, which shows this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `balance` package in your LaTeX file, like

```
\usepackage{balance}
```

Before your bibliography just use `\balance`. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: This does not work for me with the current acmart class if the last page is only half a column with references.